# Passing className values using useLocation

Tags: reactjs

Im creating a project that needs to have variable styles and images dependent on the route its in so that i dont have to recreate components.

I've successfully gotten images and text in in the code below. but i am unsuccessful in getting the string value for className in the first div into the css.

Please help!

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import homeimg from "../../images/homeimg.jpg";
import consimg from "../../images/consimg.jpg";
import solsimg from "../../images/solsimg.jpg";

const Hero = () => {
 useEffect(() => {}, []);

 const location = useLocation();
 const { pathname } = location;
 let img = null;

 if (pathname === "/") {
  img = homeimg;
 } else if (pathname === "/consultants") {
  img = consimg;
 } else if (pathname === "/solutions") {
  img = solsimg;
 }

 return (


    <Fragment>
    <div
    className={
     {pathname === "/" && ("grid-home")}
     {pathname === "/consultants" && ("grid-consultants")}
     {pathname === "/solutions" && ("grid-solutions")}
    }>
     <div className='overlay'>
      <div>
       <p className='bg-dark'></p>
       <img src={img} alt='' />
      </div>
     </div>
    <div className='copy'>
     {pathname === "/" && (
      <div>
       <h1 className='text-primary'>Snorem Snipsem</h1>
       <h3 className='text-danger'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
       <p className='text-light'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br />
        Repellat nemo, in odit culpa, illo earum voluptatum
        <br />
        aliquam quaerat iure sunt, quos similique quod <br />
        Recusandae voluptates voluptatum nisi sint dicta.
       </p>
      </div>
     )}
     {pathname === "/consultants" && (
      <div>
       <h1 className='text-primary'>Lorem, ipsum.</h1>
       <h3 className='text-danger'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
       <p className='text-light'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br />
        Repellat nemo, in odit culpa, illo earum voluptatum
        <br />
        aliquam quaerat iure sunt, quos similique quod <br />
        Recusandae voluptates voluptatum nisi sint dicta.
       </p>
      </div>
     )}
     {pathname === "/solutions" && (
      <div>
       <h1 className='text-primary'>Forem, ipsum.</h1>
       <h3 className='text-danger'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
       <p className='text-light'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br />
        Repellat nemo, in odit culpa, illo earum voluptatum
        <br />
        aliquam quaerat iure sunt, quos similique quod <br />
        Recusandae voluptates voluptatum nisi sint dicta.
       </p>
      </div>
     )}
    </div>
    </Fragment>


 );
};

export default Hero;
```

Answer (score 0):

At first declare it and try to use

```
let cn = "";

if(pathname === '/'){
    cn = grid-home 
}
....

return(
    <div className={cn}>
    ..
    ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use classnames library in order to add dynamically classnames https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

```
const divClass = classNames({
    'grid-home': pathname === "/" ,
    'grid-consultants': pathname === "/consultants",
    'grid-solutions': pathname === "/solutions"
});

<div className={divClass}>
```